# Is there a way of writing this shorter without capturing lambda variables?

Tags: c++, lambda, global, capture

I'm not sure if anyone else ever makes a temporary with a shorter name when it'll be used in many lines of code, for example you need to access something a couple of classes deep and instead of chaining member access operators over and over you'll just use a shorter named temporary. I tried doing something like the following:

```
struct Car
{
    struct
    {
        struct
        {
            int height, width, depth;
        } physicalInfo;
    } information;
} objectWithARatherLongName ;

int main()
{
    auto lambda1 = [] { return objectWithARatherLongName.information.physicalInfo.height; };

    // Create a temporary for a shorter name
    auto& dimens = objectWithARatherLongName.information.physicalInfo;

    auto lambda2 = [=] { return dimens.height; };
    // Have to capture "dimens" because it's a local variable
    // And over and over again, the shorter way is preferred.
}
```

In this case auto dimens is the short named temporary, but since I want to use it in the lambda I need to capture it, which made me made think I should just use the full name that is a global. Is there a way to shorten this in the way I described but still be using the global variable? I thought about a typedef that will only work with types right? Not with actual objects.

Comment: How about giving `objectWithARatherLongName` a shorter name and making a dedicated getter to fetch deep nested field? `Car car; car.Get_PhysicalHeight();`

Comment: Don't sweat the small stuff. Use of `[] {...}` vs `[=] {...}` is really small stuff.

Comment: Not to mention that you can capture by reference, giving the implementation leeway to not even add a member to the lambda.

Comment: @StoryTeller You mean it wouldn't even contain a reference member?

Comment: Why is `lambda2` a lambda, when it could just be a straight `int &`?

Comment: @Zebrafish - It's unspecified whether or not an entity captured by reference need even have corresponding member in the lambda's capture. And it's precisely for cases like these, that this allowance is made I'd wager.

Comment: @Matteo In this example you're right. But all of my lambdas are passed as a callable to something. It's probably a bad example.

Comment: @StoryTeller: That's an implementation optimization; formally you still need the capture.  And that stops it from being convertible to function pointer, so this has a real impact.

Comment: @MSalters - I gathered the OP is worried about lugging around copies they don't need, not about getting function pointers out of their lambdas. And anyway, my comments are to follow R Shau's line of thinking. That this feels like slight premature optimization on the OP's part.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use global variables, but if you must you probably can add one more:

```
struct Car
{
    ...
} objectWithARatherLongName ;
auto& dimens = objectWithARatherLongName.information.physicalInfo;

int main() { // ...
```